# Laravel passing error message to javascript error event

Tags: javascript, laravel, dom-events

I have a table with a bunch of audio elements. These audio elements are sometimes unavailable for different reasons. When someone clicks on the play button in the audio element it sends a request back to the server. When the server detects the element is not there it needs to return a response to the audio element but the audio element is not sending a 'fetch' or a request that I can 'latch onto' in the javascript, so the response is basically just coming back to the page with the only  thing waiting for it is the audio element. (Which will play the stream if it comes in, but has no idea how to handle anything else.)

I have attached an onerror event to the audio element. Now, I can generate a response from laravel that throws an error and I can capture that error event. BUT ONLY THE ERROR EVENT.

I need to know how to attach a custom message to the error event. The error event is not reading a json response it is only an onerror javascript event so when I do this:

```
return response()->json([
     'message' => $error
], 400);
```

And capture it here:

```
function handleSourceError(e) {
                $(".spinner").hide();
                alert('Error loading: '+e.target.src+'. The file has probably been removed from the server.')
            }
            function handleMediaError(e) {
                $(".spinner").hide();
                switch (e.target.error.code) {
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
                        alert('You aborted the media playback.'); break;
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
                        alert('A network error caused the media download to fail.'); break;
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
                        alert('The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.'); break;
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                        alert('The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.'); break;
                    default:
                        alert('An unknown media error occurred.');
                }
            }

            var toArray = Array.prototype.slice;
            toArray.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')).forEach(function(audio){
                audio.addEventListener('error', handleMediaError);
                toArray.apply(audio.getElementsByTagName('source')).forEach(function(source){
                    source.addEventListener('error', handleSourceError);
                });
            });
```

I only have access to the error event itself and not the json response so therefor I do not have access to the json message.

How do I either attach a message to the error event from Laravel or accomplish what I need in some other fashion using Laravel responses, an html audio tag and javascript? (Note: the page is not reloading and the page is not looking for a response so all the normal passing of errors to the blade file will not work here.)

Comment: Where is handleSourceError used?

Comment: At the bottom of the code:   source.addEventListener('error', handleSourceError);